# Someway to buffer or wrap cin so I can use tellg/seekg?

Tags: c++, cin, istream

Is there any way to add buffering to cin so that I can effectively use tellg and seekg on that istream?  (I only need to go back about 6 characters.)  Or is there perhaps some way to wrap the stream with a (perhaps custom) istream object that acts as a buffered pipe that would allow me to use tellg/seekg to revert the stream position a few characters?  It might look like this:

```
BufferedIStream bis(cin);
streampos pos = bis.tellg();
MyObjectType t = getObjectType(bis);
bis.seekg(pos);
```

As a work-around, I'm currently reading cin to EOF into a string, and transferring that string to an istringstream, but this has numerous negative side-affects that I'd like to avoid.

The only other thing I can think to do is to overload all my scan/read functions on all my data classes with a private version (only used by the factory) where the header is assumed to already have been consumed, so that I can eliminate the need for tellg/seekg altogether.  This would work fine, but would introduce a fair-amount of ugliness.  In comparison, tellg/seekg is isolated to my factory and is just two lines of code.  I hate to dump it.

Comment: I'd recommend Nicolai Josuttis's *The C++ Standard Library*. Having written the relevant section of the chapter on IOStreams I may be biased, though. The only other alternative I'm aware of is Angelika Langer & Klaus Kreft's *IOStreams and Locales Library*. Steve Teale's *IOStreams* is rather out of date (also I did learn the basics there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a filtering stream buffer, i.e., a class derived from `std::streambuf`. To support buffered reading you'd override `underflow()` to fill the next buffer of character once the input characters are consumed. To support limited seeking the previous buffer would not be discarded but rather partly retained. In addition you'd override `seekoff()`.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

class bufferbuf
    : public std::streambuf {
    enum { size = 2000, half = size / 2 };
    char            buffer[size];
    std::streambuf* sbuf;
    std::streamoff  base;
public:
    bufferbuf(std::streambuf* sbuf): sbuf(sbuf), base() {
        auto read = sbuf->sgetn(this->buffer, size);
        this->setg(this->buffer, this->buffer, this->buffer + read);
    }
    int underflow() {
        if (this->gptr() == this->buffer + size) {
            std::memmove(this->eback(), this->eback() + half, half);
            base += half;
            auto read = sbuf->sgetn(this->eback() + half, half);
            this->setg(this->eback(), this->eback() + half, this->eback() + half + read);
        }
        return this->gptr() != this->egptr()
            ? traits_type::to_int_type(*this->gptr())
            : traits_type::eof();
    }
    std::streampos seekoff(off_type                offset,
                           std::ios_base::seekdir  whence,
                           std::ios_base::openmode which) override {
        if (this->gptr() - this->eback() < -offset
            || this->egptr() - this->gptr() < offset
            || whence != std::ios_base::cur
            || !(which & std::ios_base::in)) {
            return pos_type(off_type(-1));
        }
        this->gbump(offset);
        return pos_type(this->base + (this->gptr() - this->eback()));
    }
    std::streampos seekpos(pos_type pos, std::ios_base::openmode which) override {
        if (off_type(pos) < this->base
            || this->base + (this->egptr() - this->eback()) < off_type(pos)
            || !(which & std::ios_base::in)) {
           return pos_type(off_type(-1));
        }
        this->setg(this->eback(), this->eback() + (off_type(pos) - this->base), this->egptr());
        return pos_type(base + (this->gptr() - this->eback()));
    }
};

int main() {
    bufferbuf buf(std::cin.rdbuf());
    std::istream in(&buf);
    // ...
    std::string s0, s1;
    bool relative(false);
    if (relative) {
        while (in >> s0
               && (in.seekg(-int(s0.size()), std::ios_base::cur), in >> s1)) {
            std::cout << "read "
                      << "s0='" << s0 << "' " << "s1='" << s1 << "'\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        for (std::streampos pos = in.tellg();
             in >> s0 && (in.seekg(pos), in >> s1); pos = in.tellg()) {
            std::cout << "read "
                      << "s0='" << s0 << "' " << "s1='" << s1 << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The code above works with a couple of simple test cases. It demonstrates uses of both relative and absolute positioning. Gennerally, I find it useless to seek in streams as generally every interesting lexing can be done with just one character look-ahead. As a result, I may have missed something in the context of position. However, I expect the above code to work proper.

Comment: @MatthewBusche: for starters you might want to spell out what actually doesn't work and what you have tried [rather than complain that you got downvoted]. Aside from the small typo for the `std::streambuf* sbuf;` member the code actually does work as expected (considering that it was typed on an iphone that's not that bad). It clearly doesn't support absolute positioning, though, i.e., you'd need to either implement absolute positioning (by overriding `seekpos()` and probably maintaining a global position) or you need to seek back using relative positioning.

Comment: @MatthewBusche: which version of my code did you test against? I updated the code today and I'd think it should work with your code.

Comment: Buffer works great now.  I've deleted all posts referring to the old version, as they are not relevant to future readers.  Thanks for so much for your help.  I'll check out the book!