# Seeking to end of std::cin returns -1 error and error bit

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, stream, stdin

I'm trying to write from a Qt application to a newly created QProcess. The Qt documentation tells me to create a process and use the ::write() function to write to the standard input of the new process. It's not working so I tried some basic testing in a program with std::cin and stdin streams.

When I start an ordinary program in main() I do:

```
int result = fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); // result is -1, indicating error
result = ftell(stdin); // result is 0
```

Using the C++ std::istream I do:

```
std::cin.seekg(0, std::ios::end); // Or std::ios_base::end
int result = std::cin.tellg(); // Returns -1
bool isgood = std::cin.good(); // Returns false
```

I'm really confused. First of all I would like to know if std::cin and stdin are both the same stream, that is the standard input? One is an std::istream object, the other is a FILE typedef, _iobuf on my Visual Studio.

I'm pretty sure that seeking to the end of a stream doesn't set an error bit or EOF bit, as people use this method to seek to the end, get the size of a file and then seek back to 0 without having to clear() the error flags.

The two lines fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END) and then ftell(stdin) I have been told can be used to check if the standard input is empty or not, yet fseek() return -1 error.
I thought it was a problem with my system but I tried an online C++ compiler and I get much the same results, the only difference between that the online compiler returns -1 for ftell(stdin) instead of my Visual Studio, which returns 0.

I haven't been able to write to the standard input from my qt application, however, I can redirect the stdin to a file on my hard drive, and that does work. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe `stdin` and `ftell()` aren't a good combination nor are `std::cin` and `tellg()`. I found this answer which might be of interest: [SO: Someway to buffer or wrap cin so I can use tellg/seekg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44711735/7478597). (You might google "c++ cin tellg" to find more.)

Answer (score 2):

I would try reading from standard input the Qt way, e.g.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMessageBox>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile in;
    in.open(stdin, QFile::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream stream(&in);

    QString line;
    while(true)
    {
        line = stream.readLine();
        if(!line.isEmpty())
        {
            QMessageBox::about(0, "stdin", line);
        }
    }
}
```

You can run this very simple widget application from another application, using `QProcess`:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QProcess process;
    process.start("/full/path/to/the/receiver/application");
    if(process.waitForStarted())
    {
        process.write("Hello\n");
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

For completeness sake, this would work as well, on the reader side:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::string line;
    while(true)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        QString data(line.c_str());
        if(!data.isEmpty())
        {
            QMessageBox::about(0, "stdin", data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I forgot to delete that line. Done.